# Looking for a .NET (SQL-Server) based Testmanagement Tool

Tags: .net, sql-server, testing, software-quality

I am looking for a (simple) **test(case) management tool** like **Speed Test** (http://speedtest.codeplex.com/) or **Testlink** (http://www.teamst.org/), which is based on .NET and SQL-Server. The tool should not be complicated and easy to learn.
Can anybody recommend me alternatives of the above mentioned tools?

Comment: There are loads of commercial ones out there that is .Net based but from your post referring to Testlink etc it sounds as your are looking for a Open Source/Free tool?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it qualifies as a simple tool but the Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2008 Test Management is powerful and quite easy to learn plus it comes with a fully integrated Unit Test Framework.

Comment: I agree on this one. Its very powerful with everything integrated but license cost will run away if every tester needs VS installed.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Tester is a .Net base test management software that uses Sql Server (also MySql, Oracle or PostgreSql).

[www.enterprisetester.com](http://www.enterprisetester.com/)

It's commercial, but licensing starts at $10/year.

Also integrates tightly with Jira and TFS.